# Javascript promise - replace arrow functions

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Since the support for arrow functions in JS is still quite low, I'd like to replace them from the following code snippet:

```
Promise.all([f1(), f2()])
.then(values => { f3(values); })
.catch(values => { f4(values); });
```

Any idea how can this be achieved?

Comment: So you just want to replace `a => b` with `function(a) {return b}`?

Comment: You should probably keep your decent source code in tact and transpile to es5 if you want more backwards compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution I wrote to allow existing promise-based code work on promise-less browsers like IE11. Not perfect, but works well.

```
CanPromise = !!window.Promise;
PromiseResolve = [];
PromiseReject = [];
if (!CanPromise)
{
    window.Promise = function (f)
    {
        var p = {};
        p.resolve = function (result)
        {
            PromiseResolve.push(result);
        }
        p.reject = function (result)
        {
            PromiseReject.push(result);
        }
        return f(p.resolve, p.reject);
    };
}

//...........

PromiseResolve.length = 0;
PromiseReject.length = 0;

F1(args);
F2(args);

var AjaxTimeout = 10000;
var period = 100;
var cnt = 0;
var cntMax = parseInt(AjaxTimeout / period);

var t = setInterval(function ()
{
    if (PromiseReject.length > 0)
    {
        clearInterval(t);
        Error(PromiseReject[0]);
    }
    else if (PromiseResolve.length >= 2)
    {
        clearInterval(t);
        Success(PromiseResolve);
    }
    else if (cnt >= cntMax)
    {
        clearInterval(t);
    }
    cnt++;
}, period);
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be straight forward, just type "function" instead

```
Promise.all([f1(), f2()]).then(function(values) { 
    f3(values); 
}).catch(function(values) { 
    f4(values); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using function expressions at all in there? Do you want to avoid the `return` values? If not, just go for

```
Promise.all([f1(), f2()]).then(f3).catch(f4);
```

Comment: Oh I have additional code behind those arrows, here I simplified it for demonstration, replacing it by Fs.