# Are these parameters "extended" resolve and reject in Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am reusing some code found on Github and I came up with some code that I am not sure what it is. This is the whole code;

```
const checkifRightPw = (ctx, next) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        users.getUserByEmail(ctx.params.user_email).then((users) => {
            if (users.length > 0) {
                resolve(users);
            } else {
                reject('email doesnt exist');
            }
        });
    }).then(
        (data, err) => (ctx.body = data),
        (err) => {
            ctx.response.status = 404;
            ctx.body = err;
        }
    );
}
```

I am wondering about these lines of code:

```
(data, err) => (ctx.body = data),
   (err) => {
   ctx.response.status = 404;
   ctx.body = err;
}
```

Does **data** and **err** stand for resolve and reject here? Normally in promises there is a function call after .then so I am a bit confused about this situation here.

Comment: Undo said confusion by always first looking up how something is supposed to work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then - while the short answer to your question is "yes", that's an answer you can confirm for yourself, and shouldn't have needed asking here =)

Comment: "I am reusing some code found on Github" - understand code you get or do not use it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript promise - replace arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587294/javascript-promise-replace-arrow-functions)

Comment: This might also help if you review it https://stackoverflow.com/q/52107165/125981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let's look at this:

```
.then(
        (data, err) => (ctx.body = data),
        (err) => {
            ctx.response.status = 404;
            ctx.body = err;
        }
 );
```

1. It's passing two fat arrow functions to `.then()`.  The first is a function to be called if the promise is resolved, the second is a function to be called if it's rejected.  Logically, the structure of this is `.then(resolveCalback, rejectCallback)`.
2. The first fat arrow function has two arguments, `(data, err)`.  That's wrong.  With any standard promise implementation, there is only one argument ever passed to a `.then()` handler.  Fortunately, the implementation does not use the second argument which would always be `undefined` anyway.
3. That first fat arrow function just moves the resolved value from `data` to `ctx.body`.  Apparently, the caller of the function that returns this promise will look for the resolved value in `ctx.body`.
4. The second fat arrow function is also setting up the `ctx` object with a status and error value.  And, importantly, it is NOT rethrowing or returning a rejected promise.  So, it's changing the promise from rejected to resolved.  So, the caller will only ever get a resolved promise from this function and will apparently have to examine `ctx.response.status` to know if there is an error or not.

If the fat arrow functions are confusing you, then this snippet of code could be expressed like this using regular functions:

```
.then(function(data) {
    ctx.body = data;
    return data;
}, function(err) {
    ctx.response.status = 404;
    ctx.body = err;
});
```

---

> Does data and err stand for resolve and reject here?

No.  See my second point above.  Only `data` is valid and it contains the resolved value of the promise.  Having `err` as an argument to that first clalback is a programming error.  It is not passed there.  The reject callback is the second callback function.

> Normally in promises there is a function call after .then so I am a bit confused about this situation here.

These are fat arrow functions (a different type of function declaration).  So, there are two functions being passed to like `.then(fn1, fn2)`.  You can read about fat arrow functions [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [here on SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/).  Their main purpose is a shortcut syntax and a different treatment for the value of `this` inside the function.  In this case, the programmer likely used them for the shorter syntax since there are no references to `this`.